# Why do we need to explicitly use the implicit method on map value?

Tags: json, scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, spray

This is the working example:

```
import spray.json._

trait JsonSupport {

  implicit def string2JsValue(s: String): JsValue = {
    JsString(s)
  }

  implicit def map2JsObject(m: Map[String, JsValue]): JsObject = {
    JsObject(m)
  }

  implicit def mapString2JsObject(m: Map[String, String]): JsObject = {
    JsObject(m.map {
      case (k,v) => (k,string2JsValue(v))
    })
  }

}
```

As it stands now, it is working. But if I replace

```
implicit def mapString2JsObject(m: Map[String, String]): JsObject = {
  JsObject(m.map {
    case (k,v) => (k,string2JsValue(v))
  })
}
```

with

```
implicit def mapString2JsObject(m: Map[String, String]): JsObject = {
  JsObject(m)
}
```

then the following error occurs:

Expected: `Map[String, JsValue]`, actual: `Map[String, String]`

Why the implicit method is not doing its work and I need to call it implicitly?

Is it possible to use implicits in a way such that there is no need to write implicit methods for every possible nesting of `Map`? E.g.:

```
implicit def map1String2JsObject(m: Map[String, String]): JsObject
implicit def map2String2JsObject(m: Map[String, Map[String, String]]): JsObject
implicit def map3String2JsObject(m: Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, String]]]): JsObject
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line `case (k,v) => (k,v)` you haven't specified that the result of the case should be anything other than (String,String). To force the implicit conversion, you could write:

```
case (k,v) => (k,v:JsValue)
```

Comment: Is it possible to infer it from the constructor of `JsObject` ? I would like to completely remove the method `mapString2JsObject` and use only `map2JsObject`. Is it possible to not rely on methods like `implicit def mapString2JsObject(m: Map[String, String]): JsObject` and then `implicit def mapStringString2JsObject(m: Map[String, Map[String, String]]): JsObject` and so on... ?

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear what I am asking

Comment: That sounds like what you are needing is an implicit conversion like: `implicit def mapStringMap2JsValueMap(m: Map[String, String]): Map[String, JsValue] = m.map { case (k,v) => (k,v:JsValue) }`

Comment: It didn't solve the issue for the case of nested map. If I have a `Map[String,Map[String, String]]`, then these implicit conversions do not work. I really do not know in advance the level of nesting.